# Pronunciation in HTML

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I want to include the IPA pronunciation of an element in a semantically meaningful way. Is there an attribute or some other standard method for this?

Otherwise I'll just have to use a custom attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no attribute or element dedicated to the pronounciation of text. Use a custom `data-*` attribute if you need to mark it up semantically, and use [the IPA characters in Unicode](http://linguistlist.org/unicode/ipa.html) to include IPA pronounciation in text.

Comment: I'd be curious to know who decided to downvote this half a year later and why. Does this answer no longer apply?

Comment: No idea. Maybe someone really just doesn't like data.

Answer (score 2):

There is Ruby
http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/

However the browser support is very poor.

Comment: Looks interesting but I don't think it's meaningful in this context (i.e. as a pronunciation guide for proper nouns in English)

Comment: @michas was correct, you can use ruby, rb and rt to markup phonetic meanings semantically. more specifically, enclosing the phonetic meaning inside a ruby text (rt) element. reference html5doc for more info: http://html5doctor.com/ruby-rt-rp-element/